# How i can create drag and drop functionality over html doc?

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

I have html something like that. I want to make it editable like form builder.

Example:

> https://app.pandadoc.com/a/#/documents/BQ8wx4gSwrtETmVvFnWoXC/widgets?widget=XFWXJPW7gpJVzZEnYZFGoh

Want functionality something like example.

Comment: Rich interfaces using javascript (jquery) and other frameworks.

Comment: You're need a lot more clarity to get a quality answer.

1. Explain the screenshot
2. How can we know how to edit your code if all we know is that you "have html something like that"?
3. If you're asking how to make your page editable like form builder, that's a big question and not specific enough. You can check out Form Builder on GitHub to learn how they built it.
4. Your example link requires me to log in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question that's going to be hard to answer, but at the very least, you're going to need **JavaScript** and probably something like **jQueryUI** for some of the UI interactions.

Start with some of the resources below and go from there. When you run into specific problems, come back and ask specific questions with code that we can use to recreate and troubleshoot the problem with:

- [jQueryUI Droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) for drag and drop.
- [jQueryUI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) for functionality similar to form builder.
- [Drag and Drop File Uploading](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/) example from CSS Tricks. (this is just one implementation. There are many ways to do this.
- [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) Another drag and drop file uploader.